# Smart Contract Design: 2-step Escrow Architecture

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How can I architecture following in the most **optimal** way;
 I'm trying to have a flow between contract **A**, **B**, and **C**.
Contract **C** should be sending ERC20 to contract **B**. 
Contract **A** should be sending Ether to contract **B**. 
Contract **B** should accept the two values from contract **C** & **A**, and perform a swap between the two only if both contract **C** & **A** gives their consent to contract **B** to execute the swap of their sent values to contract **B**. 
 
 So in this specific scenario, we are dealing with a two-phase process.

Answer (score 0):

> Contract B should accept the two values from contract C & B, and
>   perform a swap between the two only if both contract C & B gives their consent to contract B

Do you mean two values from C & A and only if C & A give their consent, not C & B?

Assuming that's what you meant, I'd do something like this.

```
contract B { 
     // this mapping will store if address A has given permission for the 
     // contract to swap with address C.
     mapping (address => (address => bool)) permissionGiven;
     mapping (address => uint) ethBalance; //ether balance
     mapping (address => uint) balances; //ERC20 token balance

     function () payable { 
        ethBalance[msg.sender] = ethBalance[msg.sender].add(msg.value); 
     }

     function givePermission (address _a) public { 
        permissionGiven[msg.sender][a] = true;
     }

     function swap(address _a, address _c) public {
        if (permissionGiven[_c][_a] && permissionGiven[_a][_c]) {
           _c.transfer(ethBalance[_a]);
           transfer(_a, balances[_c]);
        }
     }

     function transfer (address _to, uint _tokens) {
         // usual ERC20 transfer function
     }
}
```

In this implementation, contracts C and A can call givePermission, passing in the addresses of A and C respectively.  Then, after depositing ether/ tokens and calling swap, the ether will be transferred to C and the tokens to A.

Comment: Yes, you're right Elizabeth, I'll correct the description, that's what I meant. However, both contract A & C should give permission before a swap is initiated.

Comment: I changed the swap function if statement to reflect that.  The way I had it before was assuming A had already given permission, and C had to call swap to check if A has given permission; if A had, then it would commence with the swap.

Comment: I see. they should, however, give permission to contract B and not each other.